# Fine structure of the hydrogen atom

Tags: atomic-physics, astronomy, spectroscopy, hydrogen

How is the fine structure of Hydrogen of importance in the astronomical observations? For example: I know that 21 cm can penetrate the cloud of interstellar dust and hence allows the mapping of the galaxy's spiral structure. Likewise what does fine structure help reveal about the universe in astronomical observations?

Comment: The 21 cm line is due to hyperfine structure not spin-orbit/fine structure.

Comment: Yes I know. I just gave an example of 21 cm stating that it is very useful in astronomical observations. And I asked how fine structure is useful in astronomy.